# Crossfilter total by group

Tags: crossfilter

Im trying to show the total number of people in each geography when they hover over using crossfilter, but my current code is only showing the total of all geographies. So what is the equivalent in crossfilter to the sql query: SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY dma

This is my code so far

```
        //geography that is being hovered over, getting dma name and removing everything that is after the comma
    sel_geog = layer.feature.properties.dma_1;
    sel_geog = sel_geog.split(",")[0];
    console.log(sel_geog);

    //crossfilter to get total number of people of each geography
    var dmaDim = voter_data.dimension(function(d) {return d.dma == sel_geog}),
    dma_grp = dmaDim.groupAll().reduceCount().value();
    console.log(dma_grp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossfilter isn't meant to be used in a way where you are building new dimensions and groups for each user interaction. It's meant to build dimensions and groups before interactions take place and then update them quickly when filtering based on user interactions.

It's not really clear from this question what your data looks like or what you are trying to do, but you probably want to create dimensions and group for your `dma` property and then build your map based on that:

```
var voter_data = crossfilter(my_data);
var dmaDim = voter_data.dimension(function(d) { return d.dma; });
var dmaGroup = dmaDim.group();
```

At this point `dmaGroup.all()` will be an array of objects that looks like `{ key: 'dmaKey', value: 10 }` where `10` is the count of all records where `d.dma === 'dmaKey'`. There are lots of ways you can aggregate differently with Crossfilter, but that may get you started.